# Prove that $\lceil \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1+\sqrt{n^2}}}{\sqrt{n^2+3+\sqrt{n^2+2}}-\sqrt{n^2+2+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}\rceil = 2n^2+n+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

First, the question: Prove that

$$\Bigg\lceil \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1+\sqrt{n^2}}}{\sqrt{n^2+3+\sqrt{n^2+2}}-\sqrt{n^2+2+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}\Bigg\rceil = 2n^2+n+3$$

The motive to this question is the following. I once saw the following "near-identity" in a facebook page

$$7(\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7}}-\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}) \approx \sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}$$

So I thought of generating similar near-identities by directly calculating

$$E(k) = \frac{\sqrt{k+\sqrt{k}}}{\sqrt{k+1+\sqrt{k+1}}-\sqrt{k-1+\sqrt{k-1}}}$$

and then look for those entries which the expression is almost an integer (for example when k=6 we have $E(6) \approx 6.991418$)

Then I got the idea that we can also find near-identities of the form

$$N(\sqrt{k+3+\sqrt{k+2}} - \sqrt{k+2+\sqrt{k+1}}) \approx \sqrt{k+1+\sqrt{k}}$$

where $N, k$ is are positive integers, by calculating

$$F(k) = \frac{\sqrt{k+1+\sqrt{k}}}{\sqrt{k+3+\sqrt{k+2}}-\sqrt{k+2+\sqrt{k+1}}}$$

and then again look for almost-integer entries. Concretely in this case, my definition of "almost-integer" here is that the number is at most 0.001 away from the integer closest to it. Numerical evidence shows that the $k$'s for which $F(k)$ is an almost-integer are $25, 36, 49, 64, 81, \ldots$ which suggest something is at play. After some pattern-guessing, I ended up with the claim in the beginning.

Direct graph plotting seems to indicate that

$$f(x) = 2x+\sqrt{x}+3 - \Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x+3+\sqrt{x+2}}-\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+1}}}\Bigg)$$

converges to 0 "from above" the x-axis, but that's as far as I can go.

Also, calculating $E(k)$ also yields the following two claims (which is also beyond my reach at this point)

$$\Bigg\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{2n(2n+1)+1+\sqrt{2n(2n+1)}}}{\sqrt{2n(2n+1)+1+\sqrt{2n(2n+1)+1}}-\sqrt{2n(2n+1)-1+\sqrt{2n(2n+1)-1}}}\Bigg\rfloor = 2n(2n+1)+n$$

and

$$\Bigg\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{2n(2n-1)+\sqrt{2n(2n-1)}}}{\sqrt{2n(2n-1)+1+\sqrt{2n(2n-1)+1}}-\sqrt{2n(2n-1)-1+\sqrt{2n(2n-1)-1}}}\Bigg\rfloor_{0.5} = 2n(2n-1)+n-0.5$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor_{0.5}$ is the greatest integer or half-integer less than $x$, for example, $\lfloor 1.501 \rfloor_{0.5} = 1.5$

Any help would be highly appreciated.
(PS. this is not my homework, just a curiosity)

Comment: Hint :$$\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b-\sqrt c }=\frac{\sqrt a\cdot (\sqrt b+\sqrt c)}{(\sqrt b-\sqrt c)\cdot (\sqrt b+\sqrt c)}=\frac{\sqrt a\cdot (\sqrt b+\sqrt c)}{b- c }$$

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how much this could help you : for large values of $n$, the expansion of $$F(n)= \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1+\sqrt{n^2}}}{\sqrt{n^2+3+\sqrt{n^2+2}}-\sqrt{n^2+2+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}$$ is given by $$2 n^2+n+3-\frac{1}{4 n^2}+\frac{1}{16 n^3}+\frac{9}{16 n^4}-\frac{45}{64
   n^5}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^6\right)$$ and the difference between $F(n)$ and $G(n)=2 n^2+n+3$ is always negative and smaller than $1$. The largest difference is obtained for $n=-2$ for which $F(-2)=8.48432$ and $G(-2)=9$.